# .net Microsoft.Exchange.WebService.dll protocols

Tags: .net, protocols, exchange-server

Microsoft Exchange use few protocols. I can't find information which protocols are used in Microsoft.Exchange.WebService.dll https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data(v=exchg.80).aspx

Anybody known?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg134035.aspx) documentation.

Exchange Server uses a proprietary protocol called MAPI.It also supports POP3, IMAP, SMTP, and EAS.